# Faster way to format a string than format=$(printf ...)?

Tags: bash

I have a variable $id that is a number, for example 51, I want this number to have 11-digit base like: 00000000051.

I tried printf:

```
format=$(printf "% 011d" $id)
```

But it slows my program enormously, is there another method other than printf faster?

any ideas ?

Comment: The answer given is probably the best solution. Just want to add this link with examples of additional methods to zero pad a variable.

http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/04/different-ways-to-zero-pad-number-or.html

Answer (score 9):

`printf` isn't slow. `$()` is slow. Don't use it when avoidable; in this case, avoiding command substitution calls for use of `printf -v` to pass the name of a variable in which to store output.

```
printf -v format '%011d' "$id"
```

By the way -- in ksh93 (unlike bash), `value=$(printf ...)` is automatically optimized to directly store the result in the value without forking a subshell, so there your original code would be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not ideal, but it works:

```
#/bin/bash

id=51
formatted=00000000000$id

# The space before the negation is required
echo ${formatted: -11}
```

Comment: `printf` is also "native" -- a [POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) shell builtin. (Though admittedly `-v` is an extension).

Comment: Note that the `((...))` here are just redundant grouping parentheses, not the arithmetic statement (which would be wrong anyway; you would want the arithmetic *expression* `$((...))` instead). The argument for substring expansion is already evaluated in an arithmetic context. `${formatted:${#formatted} - 11}` is sufficient.

Comment: `${name:...}` is already `bash`-specific (or at least, non-standard) :). Support for negative offsets was added in version 4.2.

Comment: Extremely tangential, but while we're talking about doing this with parameter expansions, support for `printf`-style formatting seems like it would be a nice addition to the `@` operator. Something like `${id@F% 011d}`.

Comment: @chepner Is there a way to do the concatenation inline rather than with a separate assignment?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, since you can't nest expansions. (I'm thinking of something like `${${id/#/00000000000}: -11}`, which, indicidentally, *does* work in `zsh`).

Comment: Instead of adding lots of zeros and removing them, you can also add just the right number: define a global variable `_zeros11=00000000000` and then `format=${_zeros11::11-${#id}}$id`. Note that this solution, your solution and Charles Duffy's answers exhibit different behaviors when `id` is not a number with no more than 11 digits, (or when `id` has leading zeros).